# Why do amphiprotic substances react to completion in acidic and basic conditions?

Tags: acid-base

I was under the impression that amphiprotic substances were usually weak acids/bases. If this is the case, how could their reactions go to completion in more acidic/basic environments?

e.g. my textbook says that

$\ce{H2PO4-(aq) + OH-(aq) -> HPO4^2- (aq) + H2O (l)}$

Wouldn't this in all other cases be an equilibrium? Or is it still an equilibrium, just so much shifted to the RHS that we consider it fully forward due to the excess of OH provided by the basic solution?

Any responses appreciated :)

Comment: It is an equilibrium all right, just shifted to one side.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Textbook probably simplifying it to as to not have to explain LCP etc. Anyhow, I think only considering the forward reaction is fine for simple purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate form of a chemical reaction is determined by the context or purpose the reaction is describing or illustrating.

- Unidirectional reactions for titrations, synthesis, reaction schemas
- Bidirectional reactions to point out equilibrium, e.g. for pH or concentration calculations
- Substance-level reactions if focus is on used reactants and formed products.
- Ion level reactions, if focus is on involved particles, excluding bystanders, mostly for redox or precipitation reactions.